# CS50 pset2 Vigenere code - Outputs one incorrect letter

Tags: c, vigenere, cs50

New to this site and to programming.  I've looked through the previous questions under this topic and tried any number of fixes, but I keep having the same problem.

My program runs fine and gives me the output I expect, with the exception of the letter 'B' or 'b'.  Every other letter encrypts as it should.  Where did I go wrong?

EDIT - When I encrypt the message, "Meet me at the park" with a key of "bacon", I should get: Negh zf av huf pcfx.  Instead I get: Tegh zf av huf pcfx

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //Get key in commandline argument.  Prompt until key is given.
    string key = argv[1];
    int key_length = strlen(key);

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid command. Please specify key.");
        return 1;
    }
    //Make sure only alphabetical chars are used in key.
    for (int i = 0; i < key_length; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(key[i]))
        {
        printf("Invalid command. Please specify key.");
        return 1;
        }
    }

    //Get message to be encrypted
    string plain = GetString();

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < strlen(plain); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(plain[i]))
        {
            if (isupper(plain[i]))
            {
                plain[i] = (((plain[i] - 65) + (key[j%key_length] - 65)) % 26) + 65;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (islower(plain[i]))
                {
                plain[i] = (((plain[i] - 97) + (key[j%key_length] - 97)) % 26) + 97;
                j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", plain);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give the input, expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should enforce that `argc == 2` before accessing `argv[1]`. Otherwise you might take the `strlen` of a null (or other invalid) string.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! Turns out I misidentified the problem.  My code wasn't responding well to the uppercase letters.  I think I've got it working now thanks to all your insights.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that the plaintext letters are the same case as the key letters.  The problem you're seeing with the capital M not being encoded correctly is because of this.

First convert all characters in the key to upper case:

```
    if (!isalpha(key[i]))
    {
        printf("Invalid command. Please specify key.");
        return 1;
    } else {
        key[i]=toupper(key[i]);
    }
```

Then when you're encoding, assume the key is uppercase.  Also, instead of adding or subtracting the ASCII values for A and a, just use the character constants instead.  It makes your code more readable.

You also don't need separate `isupper` and `islower` checks since you're already calling `isalpha` at the prior level up.

```
        if (isupper(plain[i]))
        {
            plain[i] = (((plain[i] - 'A') + (key[j%key_length] - 'A')) % 26) + 'A';
            j++;
        }
        else 
        {
            plain[i] = (((plain[i] - 'a') + (key[j%key_length] - 'A')) % 26) + 'a';
            j++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are four cases to consider

```
plain[i]    key[j]
------------------
 lower      lower
 lower      upper
 upper      lower
 upper      upper
```

Your code only handles two of those cases.

Side note: `65` should be written as `'A'` and similarly for all of the other hard-coded numbers.